# sha256 hash length

Tags: hash, sha256, sha

I want to get hash sha256 from a string, as sha256 has 256-bit length and the size of each byte is 8 bit, I think the length of hash(in a string) must be 32 characters(256/8 = 32). but the hash length is 64 characters. can anyone help me?

```
print(hashlib.sha256('lsd'.encode()).hexdigest())
```

output:

```
3fd7dcbd130286b3799aa74e7fcb1d2ecc80d4c95a158d91dfa1d6a72557f769
```

hash length is 64, shouldn't it be 32?

Comment: That's because of the hex-encoding, which generates two output bytes per byte of input. Consider `FF` = 255.

Answer (score 0):

The output characters are actually hexadecimal digits, There are 16 possible digits used to represent numbers (0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,A,B,C,D,E,F). We need only 4 bits for each hexadecimal digits, because 2^4=16.

Now we have 256 bits, and 4 bits per digit, so 256/4=64. We get 64 digits in length.